# jquery deferred.done : passing a data array to done method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using method described in https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ to make a series of ajax calls. (based on the example `$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )` in that page).

Below code works. However, I cannot figure out how to pass a data array to `.done()` method. In the below example, I have data1, data2, data3. However in real case, it could be data1, data2, ..., dataN  where 'N' can be any number. Can you help me please? I want to map 'i' value to corresponding data value.

```
function test() {
    var myArr = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        myArr.push(
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http:/c.html/" + i,
            });
        );
    }

    $.when.apply($, myArr).done(function(data1, data2, data3) {
     //do something on data1, data2, data3
    }).fail (function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        //oops..failed
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [arguments objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which is an array like object containing all the parameter passed to the function

```
function test() {
    var myArr = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        myArr.push(jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http:/c.html/" + i,
        }));
    }

    $.when.apply($, myArr).done(function () {
        $.each(arguments, function (idx, args) {
            console.log(args[0])
        })
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        //oops..failed
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tecvmxot/)

Comment: Arun, Is the order of arguments objects same as that of myArr (when method object) . Or is is the order in which the calls are completed?

Comment: It will be in the same order as the array

Comment: Arun, the solution you suggested is working if 'myArr' length is 2 or more. However, if there is only one element in myArr  ( for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++)  ), then args[0] is returning as undefined. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: yes... there is a problem like that.... try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tecvmxot/2/

Comment: Thanks!! That was the same solution I was thinking of..I thought there might be some other way so that I can avoid " if (myArr.length > 1) { } else {} " block..Thanks again..